# How to see files related uploader?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there anyway to modify a view (of a library) to show files uploaded by the user who is looking at it?

Eg: I should only see files I uploaded in a library.

Worst case, I can tackle this via permissions but prior to that - I want to see simple solutions I maybe missing.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[Me]` filter in the view. This displays the documents to only the one who uploaded them.

[image]